# Filtering via manually defined ManyToMany through models in Django

Tags: django, django-models

My models.py looks something like this:

```
class House(models.Model):
    images = models.ManyToManyField('Image', through='HouseImage')

class HouseImage(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey('House')
    image = models.ForeignKey('Image')
    order = models.IntegerField(default=99)

class Image(models.Model):
    url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I'm having trouble writing code to get all House objects and for each house an image with the lowest value in order attribute. Is there any way to do this and not hit database as many times as there is House objects?

Edit:

HouseImage table

```
house  image  order
 1       1      1  
 1       2      2
 1       3      3
 2       4      2
 2       5      1
 3       6      1
```

Image table

```
id    url
1     a
2     b
3     c
4     d
5     e
6     f
```

I need the following result in my django queryset:

```
house_id    image_url
1           a
2           e
3           f
```

I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Your question remains unclear.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac - OP implies - get all the House objects with lowest value in the `order` attribute in `HouseImage` as efficiently as possible.

Comment: If you are using postgresql, try `HouseImage.objects.distinct('house').order_by('-order')[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prefetch related to not have extra queries. For example:

```
houses = House.objects.prefetch_related('houseimage_set__image')
```

Then when you're looping the houses or whatever you're doing, you can get the lowest ordered image like so:

```
for house in houses:
    houseimages = house.houseimage_set.order_by('order')
    if houseimages:
        image = houseimages[0].image
    else:
        image = None
    …
```

EDIT: after digging into this more, it seems django will do another query every time you call `.order_by`. So in that case, you may have to order the `houseimages` manually. For example:

```
houseimages = sorted(house.houseimage_set.all(), key=lambda x: x.order)
```